# ejabberd contribution mod_apns does not work

Tags: ejabberd

I have added mod_apns to my ejabberd server. You can find this module [here](https://github.com/mrDoctorWho/ejabberd_mod_apns/blob/master/README.md).
my ejabberd.yml configuration is like this:

```
  mod_apns: 
    address: "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com"
    port: 2195
    certfile: "/Applications/ejabberd-15.10/conf/cert.pem"
    keyfile: "/Applications/ejabberd-15.10/conf/key.pem"
    password: "myPassword"
```

the address is sandbox since I am still in development phase. And I have tested my cert.pem and key.pem and they are valid and working.
I send my device token to ejabberd server like this:

```
<iq type="set" to="myEjabberdServer.com">
    <register xmlns="https://apple.com/push">
        <token>myDeviceTokenWithoutAnySpace</token>
    </register>
</iq>
```

I can see my device token is saved in apns_users database.
But I still do not get notifications when my user is offline.

Am I doing anything wrong?
Does it work with gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com?
should my device token be without space and only characters?

I appreciate your help..

Comment: Did you ask the author of the module ? This is not an ejabberd official module.

Comment: Yes, I asked but no luck.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could suggest me any module for push notifications if you know any.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked for an alternate approach. This alternate approach takes the process of triggering push notifications by the ejabberd server.
 1. Use the `mod_interact` library. This will provide you an ability to transfer your messages to another url.
2. From there on you can use the direct HTTP call for push notifications

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will try it and mark your answer as solution if it worked.

Comment: @sureshprasanna70 in my case I don;t know how to configure APNS to eJabberD server. Do you have any reference link OR suggestion to follow.

Comment: which version of ejabberd are you using?. It would be great if you open a new question with details of trouble you are facing.